# iOS : Refresh application from internet

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, newsstand-kit

I have created a Newsstand application which first download some magazine and front covers from internet , then application check the files and if they were exist app does not download files again.
So the problem is , when some new magazines will be published how can I refresh the contents to download it again ?
generally speaking in need some tips that how can I  create application like [***Distro***](http://www.engadget.com/tag/engadget+distro/) app .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a refresh button at the top of your app that connected to the website and consumed the images and showed them in your imageviews. If you don't want the user to worry about it, then you could send the push notifications with just a badgeNumber. You set your app to always check the badgeNumber. If the badgeNumber is 0 then it doesn't refresh. If the BadgeNumber is 1 or more than it refreshes. Is that kinda what you were asking? Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: good Idea , or call refreshing method in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method ?